# How to save matches within two lines conditionally with no repetition?

Tags: regex, bash, optimization, awk

With this content in input.txt:

```
START
DD strub1
EXEC RETYE EXAMPLE
END

EXEC RETYE HELLO

START
EXEC RETYE FRIEND
END

DD strub2

START
DD strub3
DD strub4
EXEC RETYE STACKOVERFLOW
END

START
DD strub5
END

START
DD strub6
DD strub7
EXEC RETYE STACKOVERFLOW
END
```

I'm trying to extract within `START` and `END` words:

- The second word of the line that matches with `DD\s.*` *(I will save only the first line matched)*
- The third word of the line that matches with `EXEC\s+REYTE\s+`

I'll not save **nothing** between the actual processed block of `START` and `END` if:

- The `EXEC RETYE` have been saved previusly,
- There is no `DD` lines.
- There is no `EXEC RETYE` lines.

---

So this is **the desired output**:

```
DD strub1
RETYE EXAMPLE
DD strub3
RETYE STACKOVERFLOW
```

---

This is the pseudocode I thought *(note that the syntaxis is not 100% correct, is only to show the idea)*:

```
BEGIN {
  c=0;
  f=0;
  split("", retye)
}
{
  /START/{c=1;f=0}; 
  /END/{c=0;f=0};

  if(c==1 && f==0) {
      /DD\s.*/{
         dd=$1,$2;
         f=1;
      };
  }; 
  if(c==1 && f==1) {
     /EXEC\s+RETYE/ {
         if($3 in retye == 0 ) {
            print dd
            print $2,$3

            retye[]=$3
         }
     };
  };
}
```

Would you think the way I'm trying to do is the best one? Do you have any alternatives to do it?

Any advice, tip or help will be apreciated, and if you need a clearer example, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: IMO, you must extract all before and after remove duplicates.

Comment: I am not very clear on the requirements. I am guessing you mean second line and third line instead of second word and third word. Also, if your third word has to match `EXEC\s+REYTE\s+` then how do you have the `overflow` block captured? If you can clear some doubts then may be I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) approach:

```
$ awk '/^START$/{dd="";exec_retye=""};
     /^DD\s.*/{if(dd=="")dd=$2};
     /^EXEC RETYE\s.*/{exec_retye=$3;exec_retye_array[exec_retye]++};
     /^END$/{
       if((exec_retye!="")&&(dd!="")&& (exec_retye_array[exec_retye]==1))
           {print dd; print exec_retye;}
        }' input.txt

strub1
EXAMPLE
strub3
STACKOVERFLOW
```

Note:

The output contains:

1. The **second** word of the line that matches with DD\s.*
2. The **third** word of the line that matches with EXEC\s+REYTE\s+

As mentioned in question.
However, your desired output shows **entire line** that matched `DD\s.*` & **2nd & 3rd word** that matched `EXEC\s+REYTE\s`. Based on the actual requirement, you can edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this as a partial solution to make life easier.... extract each of the START/END blocks to a new file called out1.txt, out2.txt etc

```
awk '/^START/{p=1;f++;next} /^END/{p=0;next} p{print >"out"f".txt"}' input.txt
```

Comment: I like the idea, and what about this: `awk '/DD.*/{print $1,$2}; /EXEC\s+RETYE/{print $2,$3}' input.txt`. And then work with the result in bash. Do you think is better? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that could work too. I like making things simple!